# RenderPartial with Popup- MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to call RenderPartial on my view and the partial view must open as a popup.

Any Suggestions how to do it?

Comment: You can have an empty layout and use a regular popup. Or you can have some fancy jquery dialog and load it using ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Well i must be interested to know how to call this through MVC View.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using JavaScript/jQuery

Method to setup your dialog (call this on page load)

```
function setupAddFeeDialog() {
    jQuery("#dlgCreateFee").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 650,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                //Insert logic for the save button

            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                jQuery(this).dialog("close");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Method to call when you want to open the dialog:

```
function addFee() {
    $.ajax({
        url: [Insert your URL where retrieving solution],
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "myId": [Variable with your ID] } //Or any other parameters you need to pass to the controller
    }).done(function (data) {
        jQuery("#divCreateFee").html(data);
        jQuery("#dlgCreateFee").dialog("open");
    });
}
```